# CoreData blocks indefinitely on first fetch?

Tags: ios, core-data, nsfetchrequest

So I have a strange situation.

When I reinstall a development build of my app, I create a CoreData database.  Some time elsewhere in my app startup sequence, I attempt a simple `NSPredicate`-filtered fetch request.

Often (not every time), this first fetch blocks indefinitely and the app requires a restart to continue normally.

I can't seem to figure out how to deal with this problem, and since I can't reproduce this reliably, every time I do something I think works it turns out later that it didn't help anything.

Any thoughts about this?

Comment: Are you sure you are not creating the managed object context in another thread and using it (or using it from another thread), so a dead lock occurs? Post some code btw...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A great way to use Core Data in iOS is to put the creation and all accesses behind a dispatch queue. So you create a serial dispatch queue in an initialize routine, then create and populate it by dispatching blocks to that queue. You can obviously do this all asynchronously, since the queue is serial. Do your fetch that way too, then when it succeeds you can post some message to the main queue and your app delegate that the app is ready to go.

When your app boots, and needs core data setup, set some flag, then block the UI, throw up a spinner, play music (whatever) until you get that fetch back.

Comment: To add to David's great reply, you can make the first fetch have a fetch limit, so it only fetches the little bit you need to display immediately.

Comment: @JodyHagins that's a great suggestion!

Comment: Brilliant.  I'll have to find some elevator music for when I block the UI.  Thanks!